# Jenkins shared library: How to create a function in groovy that takes a string + map and returns that mapped value

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to create a shared library in Jenkins that will either take mapped arguments as a parameter, or if no arguments are provided will read from a config.yml file.

In order to do this I am trying to create a global function that checks if the provided parameter exists in a map of arguments:

```
getParam(String config_var, Map args) {
    return args.config_var
}
```

When I call this like so:

```
args = [
    test_var: "Hello World!"
]

echo getParam('test_var', args)
```

it returns null. However I change getParam() like so:

```
getParam(String config_var, Map args) {
    return args.test_var
}
```

calling it returns "Hello World!"

How can I change this function to dynamically return a value in the arguments passed into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change to `return args[config_var]`

Comment: Hallelujah! This is the right answer, thank you so much. Seems silly now, it was such a small thing.